# Karma - Setting up multi-module maven project

Tags: javascript, maven, karma-runner

I have recently started working on a project with a Maven build structure that looks something like the following:

```
|- module-1/
|    |- sub-module-1/
|    |- sub-module-2/
|    | ...
|    |- web-client/
|    |    |- src/main/resources
|    |    |    |- js/
|    |    |    |- plugins/
|    |    |- pom.xml
|    |- pom.xml
|- module-2/
| ...
|- module-n/
|    |- sub-module-1/
|    |- sub-module-2/
|    | ...
|    |- web-client/
|    |    |- src/main/resources
|    |    |    |- js
|    |    |- karma.conf.js
|    |    |- pom.xml
|    |- pom.xml
```

where the components of *module-n* are built on top of *module-1* (among others). I am currently trying to use Karma to set up an environment for testing the web client (JavaScript) code base; however I am having some difficulties with the process.

With the current structure, I am able to launch and view the web client in module-n in my browser, which includes all the dependencies from module-1 (and others). However, when I run `karma start` with the below configuration file, it fails with various `'There is no timestamp for /base/xyz.js'` and 404 errors.

```
module.exports = function(config) {
  config.set({
    basePath: '',
    frameworks: ['jasmine', 'requirejs'],
    files: [
      {pattern: 'src/main/resources/plugins/**/**', included: false},
      {pattern: 'src/main/resources/js/main.js', included: false},
      {pattern: 'src/main/resources/js/**/*.js', included: false},
      {pattern: 'src/main/resources/tests/test-main.js', included: true},
      {pattern: 'src/main/resources/tests/**/*spec.js', included: false}
    ],
    exclude: [],
    preprocessors: {},
    reporters: ['progress'],
    port: 9876,
    colors: true,
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
    autoWatch: true,
    browsers: ['Chrome', 'PhantomJS'],
    singleRun: false
  });
};
```

Additionally, debugging `karma.files` shows that none of the module-1 files were loaded.

As I am pretty new to both Karma and the Maven build system, I am wondering is there a way to set up Karma to load the dependencies from module-1?

Comment: Why are you using Maven for a JavaScript project and not using bower/npm/grunt etc. for such things?

Comment: As I just started on the project, I cannot yet answer that question. :( As far as I can tell, both the back end and front end are deployed on a Tomcat server, so that may have been the decision point for going with Maven.